# SV method which can monitor any digital signal from 1bit...128bit

Tags: system-verilog, hardware, test-bench

I have a testbench SV task that can check the frequency of a 1 bit logic signal, useful to measure frequencies of clocks, valids etc... however how can I measure the frequency of a multi-bit data signal to get a rough idea of how fast samples are changing.

The problem is I don't want to care about the signal size but the compiler does. Is there anyway to pass an unspecified size logic signal into a SV task? e.g.

```
  task automatic chk_data_rate(
    ref int signal, 
    input time timeout,
    output real meas_freq
  );
    : : :
  endtask

  real f;
  logic [23:0] a;
  logic [7:0] b;
  logic [31:0] c;
  chk_data_rate(a, 1ms, f);  
  chk_data_rate(b, 1ms, f);
  chk_data_rate(c, 1ms, f);
```

Here the error is:

> xmelab: *E,TYCMPAT (test.sv,1769|38): ref formal and actual do not have equivalent data types
> on instance '$unit_0x78c03c36' (expecting datatype compatible with 'int' but found 'packed
> array [23:0] of logic' instead).

I can change int the same type as 'a' but I can't make it generic...

I could convert each signal to analyse into a single bit first and then use existing task, but it seems cumbersome...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using parameterized classes to do it. Something like in the following example:

```
module mod;
  class abc #(size = 1);
    logic [size-1:0] data;
    function new();
    endfunction
    
    task monitor();
      $display("my size is %0d", size);
    endtask
  endclass

  abc #(24) a = new;
  abc #(8) b = new;
  abc #(63) c = new;
  
  initial begin
    a.monitor;
    b.monitor;
    c.monitor;
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: Thanks this is a really nice idea thanks. It enables me to add multiple calculations on any signal, freq, avg, etc...

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to care about the signal size but the compiler does.

The following accepts a vector from 0 - 128 bits

```
module tb ();
  
  task automatic chk_data_rate(
    ref logic [127 : 0] my_signal, 
    input time timeout,
    output real meas_freq
  );
    
    $display("my_signal = %h",my_signal);
    
  endtask

  real f;
  logic [23:0] a;
  logic [7:0]  b;
  logic [31:0] c;

  logic [127 : 0] a_stub;
  logic [127 : 0] b_stub;
  logic [127 : 0] c_stub;

  always @* begin
  a_stub = a;
  b_stub = b;
  c_stub = c;
  end

  initial begin
  a = 1;
  b = 2;
  c = 3;
  #1;
  chk_data_rate(a_stub, 1ms, f);  
  chk_data_rate(b_stub, 1ms, f);
  chk_data_rate(c_stub, 1ms, f);
  $finish;
  end
  
endmodule
```

Cadence, Mentor, Aldec and Synopsys produce:

```
# my_signal = 00000000000000000000000000000001
# my_signal = 00000000000000000000000000000002
# my_signal = 00000000000000000000000000000003
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately that doesn't work for me, maybe it depends on which compiler is used... Declaring a 128 bit logic I get the same error. i.e. 

*E,TYCMPAT, ref formal and actual do not have equivalent data types on instance '$unit_0x78c03c36' (expecting datatype compatible with 'packed array [127:0] of logic' but found 'packed array [23:0] of logic' instead).

Type and size must match

Comment: check again your code. Looks like you did not use 'stubs' in the arguments to the task.

Comment: Yes you're right sorry, I didn't see your assignment to the stubs signal thanks. I used ref because I want the task to see changes in the original signal but maybe it's not needed.